# Можно ли обойтись без онлайн кассы?

Tags: онлайн-коммерция

есть сайт где продается одна услуга( Видео тренинг )
Хотели подключить кассу, но касса берет достаточно большие проценты
Если мы создадим аккаунты, Яндекс, Киви, приват24 и оплата картой, можем сами принимать платежи?
Там лишь одна кнопка для оплаты

Comment: Это надо спрашивать у юристов, а не у программистов

Comment: Проценты будут платить покупатели. К тому же это может быть не очень законно